# Calculate how to cover an area by recepetion tovwers

Tags: catchment-area

I am working in a Nature Reserve and we are putting up towers that will be used to to track certain animal with collars on.
The towers work on line of site only. We must place the towers in a matter with the least overlap and cover the whole park area. More smaller areas will have the most accurate and current results.

Things to consider are:

- Terrain: will break line of site
- Hight of tower - will determine area covered

How would you go about creating reception based on line of site and the terrain?

I understand first we would need some kind of terrain map with contours etc. The problem is the ones I can find are only 5m intervals, but a 1m change in tower hight would have a huge impact on the coverage of the tower.

We must assume power settings and range are theoretical, and will be tested in the field